# How to upload a file to Amazon S3 from iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, amazon-s3

Iam developing one application.In that i want to use the Amazon S3 service.I got the AWS SDK for IOS.And i added that framework to my application.After that what iam doing for perform the operations with Amazon S3.Please guide me how to do that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess [this](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/mobile/sdkforios/gsg/) would help you through.........

Happy Programming .....